Grafana: Can't query for alerts
I have several targets I'm monitoring with Grafana, each target sending metrics to Prometheus remote-write. I also have alert rules configured in Grafana itself. I wanted to have a simple table in Grafana that lists all my targets in rows with columns (name, IP, and a few other properties) and a column that simply tells me how many alerts are active right now on that target.
I can't seem to find a way to query for alerts. Seems like a limitation in Grafana? or I haven't found yet how do it with promql. I know that Grafana has a panel dedicated for alerts, but that doesn't help me here. Ideas?

AFAIK, if alerts are on the Grafana's side, promql wouldn't help as Grafan doesn't expose this. In theory you probably could try to extract them using Grafana's API and JSON plugin.

Grafana itself exposes internal metrics on the /metrics endpoint. You can add a target to Prometheus to scrape the Grafana instance and collect these metrics.
After a first glance, there are a few metrics related to grafana alerting (look for grafana_alerting_*). Since these metrics will be available in Prometheus you should be able to query them as usual.

As far as I know (and please correct me if I'm wrong) grafana_alerting_* only includes metrics for aggregated state of alerts, and no info on per-alert (or even per-eval-group) basis.

yep, I checked a bit more and there are only aggregated metrics about the status but not for individual alerts. I guess what you need is more like the ALERTS metric from alertmanager.
